# How can I add a custom role capability to use in a custom plugin?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I need to add custom capabilities to user roles, something along the lines of:

`$role->add_cap('xtc5000'); // 5000 can be different`

I need to use the `5000` value in another plugin for some specific functionality. I need to extract the capability starting with `xtc` and then use the number (which can be different).

**Pseudo-code:**

```
foreach ($caps as $cap) {
    if (stripos($cap, 'xtc') !== false) {
        $number = (int) str_replace('xtc', '', $cap);
    }
}

// Use $number for some other functionality
```

Can I add custom named capabilities or am I restricted to standard WordPress ones?

The reason I want to this is to use WordPress' tables instead of creating separate options or a separate table. It would be one extra capability per user role.

As an example for my request, I need all authors to be able to post 1000 articles, all editors to be able to post 2000 and all contributors 3000. This is just an example.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to use the numbers for? It sounds like you'd be better served having user meta, with a meta key of  `xtc` and the value being whatever number you need.

Comment: I need all authors to be able to post 1000 articles and all editors to be able to post 2000 and all contributors 3000. This is just an example.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to have a separate setting/option that mapped roles to article limits. Like `['author' => 1000, 'editor' => 2000]`. Then just get the current user role and look up its value in that option whenever you need that information. Storing data in a role *name* seems like an inappropriate use of roles to me.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I know it does, that's why I'm looking for a more elegant solution. I wanted to avoid all options, but this was my initial plan, followed by role metas/capabilities.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid setting extra options?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I thought I could add custom properties to roles, just like you can add custom meta to users or posts. I'm also adding other functionality, and I was able to do it using custom meta or user meta, and keep the plugin light in terms of setting too many options.

Comment: Roles in WordPress do not have metadata. Or even much data, they're just a slug and a name that is mapped to some capabilities. If you want to define additional data for roles you'll need a custom option or a custom table, though a custom tables seems like overkill since you won't be querying them.

Comment: I noticed that I have lots of old capabilities from old/removed plugins in there, so I thought it might be a good place to add a custom capability. The only thing that sounds a bit hacky, is the `foreach` loop and the `str_replace` function. But it should do the job.